# Type error while trying to use marked module

Tags: node.js, node-modules, javascript-marked

```
const marked = require('marked');
articleSchema.pre("validate", function(next) {
    if (this.title){
        this.slug = slugify(this.title, {lower: true, strict: true})
    }
    if(this.markdown){
        this.sanitaizeHTML = marked(this.markdown);
    }
    next();
})
```

When I try to use marked module as a function I will return typeError

TypeError: marked is not a function
at model. (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\models\article.js:42:30)
at callMiddlewareFunction (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\kareem\index.js:628:27)
at next (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\kareem\index.js:93:7)
at Kareem.execPre (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\kareem\index.js:122:8)
at Kareem.wrap (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\kareem\index.js:368:8)
at model.$__validate (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\kareem\index.js:502:11)
at C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2576:10
at new Promise ()
at model.validate (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2575:10)
at model.validateBeforeSave (C:\Users\araiz\OneDrive\Desktop\Test_001\node_modules\mongoose\lib\plugins\validateBeforeSave.js:35:12)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is saying that `marked` is not a function. This usually happens if the required module was not imported properly or the module itself is not exporting a function as expected.

There could be a few reasons for this:

1. The `marked` package is not installed. You can install it using `npm install marked`.
2. You have a different version of the `marked` package that might not be compatible. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the package:

```bash
npm uninstall marked
npm install marked
```

3. There could be some issues with your `node_modules` folder. Try deleting it and reinstalling your packages:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

4. There might be some confusion in how you're trying to use `marked`. `marked` should be a function if properly imported. It converts Markdown into HTML. Make sure you're using it correctly:

```js
const marked = require('marked');

// Use it as a function
console.log(marked('# Marked in Node.js\n\nRendered by **marked**.'));
```

Make sure to check if any of these solutions work for you. If not, please provide more information and we can find a more detailed solution.